# How can I increase my server space?

Tags: ssl, drive

My website looks like this..(html version) is it an issue of space? it maybe full. Can you take a look and let me know what needs to be done?

https://wizkidsclub.com/books/

Comment: Pay to an admin to do work for you. We aren't free tech support here.

Answer (score 1):

Websites look like that when CSS fails to load. I'm not going to review it in detail but the first obvious issue is the attempt to load a CSS file from `wp-content/cache/autoptimize` which fails.

It's possible this file has been removed by something, or the plugin that creates these cache files isn't working correct. It's also possible that the server is full and it is unable to create these cache files.

If you are concerned you may be out of space, then the first obvious thing would be to get the host to check there is sufficient available space on the server.

If not, I would suggest clearing the autoptimize cache if it has the option, or otherwise remove the plugin, re-test the site, then re-install it.